# Partial black background in UIWebView on iOS7 after setting content inset

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a problem with `UIWebView` on iOS7:

First I'm setting the content inset for my web view scrollview:

```
[webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Then when web view loads an empty page there is a black rectangle at the bottom of the web view, that has the height 40.

It's for sure because of content inset, and I met this problem only on iOS7. How can I solve this? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code, it is not the best solution, but it will get rid the black rectangle:

```
[webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, -40, 0)];
```

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, iOS7 `UIWebView` does not play nice at all with custom insets and content size. It always breaks under certain conditions. We use a webview for a rich text editor, so we had to manage a volatile `contentEditable="true"` webview.

What we ended up doing was to take the `UIWebDocumentView`/`UIWebBrowserView` (let's call it "internal view") from the `UIWebScrollView` and add it as a subview in a scrollview of our own. To do this safely, we iterate the subviews of `webView.scrollView` and took the one whose class name has a `UIWeb` prefix. (You have to remember that iOS6 `UIWebScrollView` contains shadows as well.)

Now you have to manage your scrollview. What we did was observe changes of the `frame` property of the internal view and update the scrollview's contentsize accordingly.

Comment: All these belong to a private API? If so my app could be rejected from store.

Comment: You should not access any of these by name, which should make it relatively safe. You are shuffling views from one superview to another.